# Gatling - Looping through JSON array

Tags: json, scala, jsonpath, gatling

I have a block of code which needs to loop through a JSON array which is obtained from response of a REST service. ([Full gist available here](https://gist.github.com/neilghosh/7f1ef88e45c44791210f).)

```
.exec(http("Request_1")
  .post("/endPoint")
  .headers(headers_1)
  .body(StringBody("""REQUEST_BODY""")).asJSON
  .check(jsonPath("$.result").is("SUCCESS"))
  .check(jsonPath("$.data[*]").findAll.saveAs("pList")))
.exec(session => {
  println(session)
  session
})
.foreach("${pList}", "player"){
 exec(session => {
    val playerId = JsonPath.query("$.playerId", "${player}")
    session.set("playerId", playerId)
  })
 .exec(http("Request_1")
    .post("/endPoint")
    .headers(headers_1)
    .body(StringBody("""{"playerId":"${playerId}"}""")).asJSON
    .check(jsonPath("$.result").is("SUCCESS")))

}
```

The response format of the first request  was

```
{
  "result": "SUCCESS",
  "data": [
    {
      "playerId": 2
    },
    {
      "playerId": 3
    },
    {
      "playerId": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

And `playerId` shows up in the session as

```
pList -> Vector({playerId=2, score=200}, {playerId=3, score=200}
```

I am seeing in the second request the body is

```
{"playerId":"Right(empty iterator)}
```

Expected : 3  requests with body as

```
 {"playerId":1}
 {"playerId":2}
 {"playerId":3}
```

I can loop over the resulting array successfully if I save just the playerIds:

```
.check(jsonPath("$.data[*].playerId").findAll.saveAs("pList")))
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I managed to get the requests you're looking for sent out (although still getting a 404, but that might be server-side or the request your gist is sending might be missing something). The trick was to give up on JsonPath entirely:

```
.exec(http("Request_10")
  .get("gatling1")
  .headers(headers_10)
  .check(jsonPath("$.result").is("SUCCESS"),
  jsonPath("$.data[*]").ofType[Map[String,Any]].findAll.saveAs("pList")))
.foreach("${pList}", "player") {
  exec(session => {
    val playerMap = session("player").as[Map[String,Any]]
    val playerId = playerMap("playerId")
    session.set("playerId", playerId)
  })
```

Here, the `jsonPath` check can automatically store your JSON object as a map, and then you can access the player ID by key. The value type doesn't have to be `Any`, you could use `Int` or `Long` if all your values are numbers. If you want more info on what went wrong with `JsonPath`, read on.

---

Your first problem is that `JsonPath.query()` doesn't just return the value you're looking for. From the [JsonPath readme](https://github.com/gatling/jsonpath#implementation):

> JsonPath.query("$.a", jsonSample) gives you Right(non-empty iterator). This will allow you to iterate over all possible solutions to the query.

Now, when it says `Right(non-empty iterator)`, I assumed that meant the iterator was not empty. However, if you try this:

```
val playerId = JsonPath.query("$.playerId", session("player").as[String]).right.get
println(playerId)
```

...it prints "empty iterator". I'm not sure whether it's a problem with `JsonPath`, the `jsonPath` check, or usage somewhere in between, but there's not quite enough documentation for me to want to dig into it.

Comment: WHich Map import did you use ? For me it shows error Cannot find JsonFilter type class for type scala.collection.Map[String,Any]
00:28:05.986 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ -       ,jsonPath("$.data[*]").ofType[Map[String,Any]].findAll.saveAs("pList")))

Comment: @NeilGhosh I didn't import anything. What version of Gatling are you using? `ofType` and/or `ofType[Map]` might be new in RC1 or RC2.

Comment: gatling-charts-highcharts-2.0.0-RC2

Comment: Sorry I had the extra import scala.collection.Map , removed that to get rid of this error

Comment: With with the dataType Any I have a problem in comparison. Basically the player ID is a number so   if (playerId < ${"playerIdFromSession"} giving me compilation error value < is not a member of Any)

Comment: Perfect ! This is what happens when you try Gatling before learning Scala :) The following worked if (playerId.asInstanceOf[Long] < session("playerIdFromSession").as[Long]) {

Comment: Just another quick question, in your answer playerId is a String so we directly assigned it to a variable. In my real test case playerId is a map again , when I typcast using playerId..asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]] it gives me error java.lang.ClassCastException: org.boon.core.value.LazyValueMap cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map. I was wondering how to handle nested JSON after getting type "Any"  from session

Comment: @NeilGhosh That I'm not sure of, and may be a limitation of the implementation of the `jsonPath` check. I think your best bet would be to post a new question on the Google group specifically regarding `jsonPath().ofType[]` and whether it can handle nested maps/how to do so.

Comment: Thanks Michelle I'll do that in a while with a proper test case , was just wondering if you had some suggestion over the top of you head :)