# Gatling: JsonPath extract multiple values

Tags: json, scala, jsonpath, gatling

I'm building a gatling 2.1.3 scenario and I need to extract data from a json body.

Example of the body:

```
[
  {
    "objectId": "FirstFoo",
    "pvrId": "413"
    "type": "foo",
    "name": "the first name",
    "fooabilities": {
      "foo1": true,
      "foo2": true
    },
    "versions": [23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 23, 23],
    "logo": [
      {
        "type": "firstlogo",
        "width": 780,
        "height": 490,
        "url": "firstlogos/HD/{resolution}.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "objectId": "SecondFoo",
    "pvrId": "414"
    "type": "foo",
    "name": "the second name",
    "fooabilities": {
      "foo1": true,
      "foo2": false
    },
    "versions": [23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 23, 23],
    "logo": [
      {
        "type": "secondlogo",
        "width": 780,
        "height": 490,
        "url": "secondlogos/HD/{resolution}.png"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I have this code trying to extract de data:

```
exec(
  http("get object")
    .get(commons.base_url_ws + "/my-resource/2.0/object/")
    .headers(commons.headers_ws_session).asJSON
    .check(jsonPath("$..*").findAll.saveAs("MY_RESULT"))) (1)
  .exec(session => {
    foreach("${MY_RESULT}", "result") { (2)
      exec(session => {
        val result= session("result").as[Map[String, Any]]
        val objectId = result("objectId")
        val version = result("version") 
        session.set("MY_RESULT_INFO", session("MY_RESULT_INFO").as[List[(String,Int)]] :+ Tuple2(objectId, version))
      })
    }
    session
  })
```

My goal is:
To extract the objectId and the 9th value from the version array.
I want it to look as Vector -> [(id1, version1),(id2, version2)] in the session to reuse later in another call to the API.

My concerns are:
(1) Is this going to create entries in the session with the complete sub objects? Because in other answers I was that is was always a map that was saved ("id" = [{...}]) and here I do not have ids.

(2) In the logs, I see that the session is loaded with a lot of data, but this foreach is never called. What could cause this ?

My experience in Scala is of a beginner - there may be issues I did not see.

I have looked into this issue: [Gatling - Looping through JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289334/gatling-looping-through-json-array) and it is not exactly answering my case.

Comment: The `(1)` line looks suspicious, it will return all substructures, probably not what you want. `(2)` might miss a string interpolator prefix, sorry I am not familiar with gatling.

Comment: (Just checked the link you mentioned. `(2)` is probably the correct syntax, just a bit unusual.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it with a regex.

```
.check(regex("""(?:"objectId"|"version"):"(.*?)",.*?(?:"objectId"|"version"):\[(?:.*?,){9}([0-9]*?),.*?\]""").ofType[(String, String)].findAll saveAs ("OBJECTS")))
```

I can then use this

```
foreach("${OBJECTS}", "object") {
  exec(
    http("Next API call")
      .get(commons.base_url_ws + "/my-resource/2.0/foo/${object._1}/${object._2}")
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Some problems: if -for example- `fooabilities` contain `objectId` and `version` keys, your regex might match there too. It will not match if there are less than 10 things are there for versions, empty 10th version also matches (though it is not part of a valid JSON). The order of `objectId` and `version` are assumed to be this, but JSON does not specify order. In case `objectId` contains `,`, your pattern stops there.