# In Gatling/Scala how do I convert a jsonPath into an array?

Tags: scala, gatling

The following check produces an error claiming

> No member of type class JsonFilter found for type Seq[String]

```
...
.check(
jsonPath("$..foo").ofType[Seq[String]]
   .transform((a) => {println(a);a})
   .saveAs("bar")
)
```

Given the following json, I'd expect the out put to look like: `List(f1, f2, f3)`

```
{
"one": {"foo": "f1"},
"two": {"foo": "f2"},
"three": {"foo": "f3"},
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAll` is what I was searching for.

```
.check(
jsonPath("$..foo").findAll
   .transform((a) => {println(a);a})
   .saveAs("bar")
)
```

#### Sources

- https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/http/http_check/?highlight=jsonpath#multiple-results
- [Gatling - Looping through JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289334/gatling-looping-through-json-array)